# В href ничего не передается, немогу понять

Tags: javascript

нашел пример который откроет все ссылки в новом окне с необходимым id
Но в href ничего не передается, а со знаниями js не настолько хорошо чтобы понять...
Может подсобите?
Пожалуйста ;)

```
function OpenAllLinks() { 
var href = document.getElementById('edit-615').getAttribute('href');
var http = "href"; 
var win1 = window.open(http); }
```

Comment: Может `window.open(href)`?

Comment: В строке `var http = "href"; ` Вы записываете в `http` текст `"href"`, а не значение переменной `href`, Вам нужно, как минимум, `var http = href;`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! В адресной строке null

Answer (score 0):

А что ты делаешь вообще? зачем ты переменной `http` присваиваешь строку `"href"`? Так потом еще и передаешь её в функцию `window.open()`.
Если я правильно понял, что тебе нужно, то:

```
function OpenAllLinks() { 
var href = document.getElementById('edit-615').getAttribute('href');
var win1 = window.open(href); }
```

Будет правильным решением

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но не работает...